# Prevent or handle time out with XmlReader.Create(uri)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, xmlhttprequest

Sometimes I am getting a time out exception when reading an XML via a URL. Is there something I can do to prevent this, or is this a problem with the remote server? Below is my simple code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(XmlReader.Create(this.RssUrl));
```

I cam across a post that says KeepAlive may help, but I do not know how to pass that setting into the code above (or if that is even the correct solution): http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t95843-system-webexception-the-operation-has-timed-out.html

This is the exception, please help!

```
Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
Stack Trace: 

[WebException: The operation has timed out]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +5375213
   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials) +69
   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials) +3929371
   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn) +54
   System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext) +144
   System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri) +8
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem earlier and found this unanswered question. An option I have found is to prevent the request from timing out at all, which you can do creating your own [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) with a timeout of [Timeout.Infinite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite.aspx) and passing it into the XmlReader.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(this.RssUrl);
request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    // Blah blah...
}
```

You can also set the KeepAlive if you use a HttpWebRequest, although it is actually true by default, so it should not make any difference.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.RssUrl);
request.KeepAlive = true;
```

Comment: Hi Fara
I have used the exactly as you have posted , but i am still getting this error.